# Python - sparse vectors/distance calculation

Tags: python, vector, scipy, distance, sparse-matrix

I'm looking for dynamically growing vectors in Python, since I don't know their length in advance. In addition, I would like to calculate distances between these sparse vectors, preferably using the distance functions in scipy.spatial.distance (although any other suggestions are welcome). Any ideas how to do this? (Initially, it doesn't need to be efficient.)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: For sparse distances, see [pairwise_distances](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html) in scikit-learn. With scipy.spatial.distance, you'd have to e.g. cdist( X.todense(), Y.todense(), metric=... )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regular python lists (which are dynamic) as vectors. Trivial example follows.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import sqeuclidean
a = [1,2,3]
b = [0,0,0]
print sqeuclidean(a,b) # 14
```

As per aganders3's suggestion, do note that you can also use numpy arrays if needed:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([1,2,3])
```

If the sparse part of your question is crucial I'd use scipy for that - it has support for sparse matrixes. You can define a 1xn matrix and use it as a vector. This works (the parameter is the size of the matrix, filled with zeroes by default):

```
sqeuclidean(scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((1,3)),scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((1,3))) # 0
```

There are [many kinds](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html?highlight=scipy.sparse#scipy.sparse) of sparse matrixes, some dictionary based (see comment). You can define a row sparse matrix from a list like this:

```
scipy.sparse.csr_matrix([1,2,3])
```

Comment: Good answer. I'd also note you can use numpy arrays, which may be beneficial in other cases.

Comment: I think he means vectors with most elements missing. They can be represented as dictionaries: { 1:5, 2:4, 101:15 }. Now how do you calculate distance?

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Do these SciPy sparse matrices grow dynamically, or do you need to give a fixed size in advance during initialization (since I don't know these lengths beforehand)?

Comment: You can resize *some* of them dynamically. `lil_matrix`, for example, implements the `reshape` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it in numpy:

```
import numpy as np


a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([0, 0, 0])

c = np.sum(((a - b) ** 2)) # 14
```